# A pastoral riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

As if it were to read your mind,
My first tells which way you're inclined.
My next, if you should like to ride,
You'll find wherever roads divide.

In meadows green I toss and turn,
Or else hold sway where fires burn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is

> Pitchfork.

As if it were to read your mind,
My first tells which way you're inclined.

> *Pitch* is a description of angular direction.

My next, if you should like to ride,
You'll find wherever roads divide.

> A *fork* in the road is where roads divide.

In meadows green I toss and turn,

> *Pitchforks* are used in fields.

Or else hold sway where fires burn.

> *Pitchforks* are also found in imaginings of Hellscape.

Comment: Is this a known riddle or are you just on point?

Comment: @Goingham I'd never heard it before, but it could be a riddle?

Comment: It's my own composition, if that's what you mean

Comment: I figured the "Or else hold sway where fires burn" to be related to an angry mob carrying torches and pitchforks.